# How can I output my object including it's nested objects in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rides and Waypoints, where one Ride has many Waypoints.
I use this relation in may parts of my app without problems.

Now I am playing around with the includes() method to eager load all rides and their waypoints.

So I do this:

```
@rides = Ride.all.includes(:waypoints)
render json: @rides
```

But this only outputs the rides and not the waypoints.

I also tried

```
render text: @rides.inspect
```

This also returns only the rides and not the waypoints.

I know that for Json responses there are other ways to include the nested objects but I want to start with the basics and am wondering why the above does not return the nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Ride.all.as_json(include: :waypoints)
```

Comment: This works, but it does not answer me why my first code, that I read in so many documentations, does not work. This is only the first part of my problem - in the second part I need to decorate the waypoints. That's why I want my first code to work...Hope that makes sense ;)

Comment: In your code "includes" is an ActiveRecord relation method, which performs a second query for waypoints in case you call something like ride.waypoints.map.  But Ride.all.includes(:waypoints) returns an array of Ride objects without any additional data (you can omit 'all' BTW).

Answer (score -2):

If you override the `to_json` method of your `Ride` class, you can customise whats rendered to JSON. See [Hash](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_json)